# PayPal custom button code. "User has to accept payment"

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I've created custom PatPal button code.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="from-to@from-to.com">

Price:
<input  name="amount" type="number" step="0.01" value="1.00"> GBP
<br/><br/>
Name/Service Description:<br/>
 <textarea cols="40" rows="5" style="width:400px;height:200px;word-break: break-word;" required name="item_name"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://fromtotranslations.com/?wp_paypal_ipn=1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="WPPayPal_BuyNow_WPS_US">
<br/><br/><br/>
<input type="image" style="max-width:200px" src="https://i.ibb.co/YcBX3Ww/paypall-button.png" border="0" name="submit">
```

I wanted to add user possibility of enter price manually.
Form seems to be working okay. Payment was made.
But I haven't it on my PayPal dashboard.

As customer I have notification, that seller have to confirm payment.

[image]

It seems, that PayPal not recognizes my email as PayPal account or maybe i don't know where to accept payment from customer.

Can You help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is `from-to@from-to.com` your PayPal business account's primary email address?

Maybe try replacing this value with the one that points to the business account where you want to be receiving the PayPal payment.

---

Meanwhile, it would seem that there is no PayPal business account associated with the email `from-to@from-to.com`, and so that is why no one has accepted the payment. If no one registers that email with PayPal to accept it, it will be automatically refunded in 30 days.